# Why does umask use this complicated numeric system?

Tags: permissions, umask

I am trying to learn how to use umask but it seems so complicated.

Besides all the subtractions that I have to make in my head seperately for directories and files every time I see a mask value, the umask seems different at different times(see bellow).

For example if I have a mask of

```
umask
0002
```

it can also be seen as

```
umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

Why does the umask give `rwxrwxr-x` and not `-------w-` in this case? When I am given 0002 I am supposed to calculate the permissions for files by 666-002 and directories by 777-002. Shouldn't then `umask -S` give me a similar thing so that I can calculate with. For example `negation-of(-------w-)`. So in one case it acts as a mask for negation and in the second case it just gives the result from what I understand. Why this ambiguous behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

That's just how the behavior of `umask` is defined:

> If **-S** is specified, the message shall be in the following format:
>
> "u=%s,g=%s,o=%s\n", , ,
>
> where the three values shall be combinations of letters from the set {
>   r, w, x}; the presence of a letter shall indicate that the
>   corresponding bit is clear in the file mode creation mask.

(from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/umask.html)

It seems logical that being able to display the mask in both forms would be useful, though admittedly the `umask(1)` man page is not terribly clear on what the `-S` option does.